# Packet field enumeration as string

Tags: enums, scapy

I would like to get the string representation of a packet field, something like:

```py
pkt[BOOTP].op == 'BOOTREPLY'
```

So far, the only cumbersome way I found is:

```py
 pkt[BOOTP].fields_desc[0].i2repr(pkt[BOOTP], 2)
```

Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sprintf](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.packet.html#scapy.packet.Packet.sprintf)

```
pkt.sprintf("%BOOTP.op%")
```